# Error: A string value is required for google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qDSl.png)Hi iam new to GCP i just started learning, when i was trying to deploy cloud sql database using terraform scripts getting this error **A string value is required for google.** Thanks inadvance.

```json
terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.0"
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "2.0.0"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that terraform version 0.13 introduces this syntax. You're using TF version 0.12 so therefore it is not working. Can you change required_version to `required_version = "0.13.0"`? Check this [discussion](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/string-value-is-required-for-google/32298).

The syntax for version v0.12 should be something like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.0"
  required_providers {
    google = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer -Heikura, yeah but terraform which i was using is **0.12** so what is the syntax for this.